# Can Angular 2 NPM modules used With Angular 4?

Tags: angular

We're starting a Greenfield project. Wanted to leverage most possible libraries. Like Angular Material, MaterializeCSS etc.

I see for many frameworks NPM packages are not yet available for Angular-4.

> Can we continue using Angular-2 modules with Angular-4?

Comment: yes. it will didn't you try. ?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer.  Angular4 is simply a new version of Angular, it isn't a rewrite, which means that any modules written for Angular will be compatible **unless the module uses version specific features**.  You would need to review each module to determine it's specific version requirements.

Comment: Angular 4 is primarily designed to be backwards compatible with Angular 2. So theoretically, yes, NPM packages initially designed for Angular 2 should work for Angular 4.

Comment: Most likely yes, but you find some libraries which need to be updated to be AoT-friendly.

Comment: @Claies We stumbled upon version specific features.

Comment: AOT specific features are problematic, hence we customized Angular-4 to use bare minimal libraries.

Comment: ok, sorry to hear that;  still, that wouldn't be something that can be addressed here, it should probably be addressed by the people who created whatever library you are dealing with.